# Strange number formating in ssas tabular?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a ssas tabular cube. I have a question regarding formatting here:

[image]

I have number 1,000,000,000.5

By using format: #,##0,.0

it gets displayed as: 1,000,000.5

I have 2 questions:

What's the logic? how is  #,##0,.0 instructing to remove 000?

Also, i would like to get rid of the decimal, and show it like 1,000,000 How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas before the decimal point that are not followed by `#` or `0` divide the result by 1000.

Whatever digits it shows will be rounded to that precision. If you want to drop the decimal rather than rounding, you can use TRUNC or INT in the measure definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following format `#,###` will give you the following.

[image: S1]